# How to avoid bone roll on "Rotation Constrained" IK bone?

Tags: rigging, inverse-kinematics

For 2d cutout animation sidefacing rig (XZ plane), movement and rotation in Y axis is restricted with constraints.However even after applying IK constraints to the IK chain and location constraints to the IK target there is still rotation in the Y direction . Also bones roll on movement.

How to avoid this ?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Actually you have a very small bone (the one on the top of your arm, called Bone) that is not constrained, that's why the other moves even though you've limited them, is it your problem? –

Comment: I have updated the blend file , now it should be fine ,The rotation limits of the last ik bone (shoulder bone) can't be  set to be in straight direction because of the axis switching on setting rotation limits.

Comment: not sure to understand but have you solved your problem? It seems like you need to set the IK chain length though...

Comment: This is a sidefacing rig for a 2d cutout animation ,The hand needs to constrained in the global XZ plane , however when the IK rotation limit is set for the bones , the limit works for all the bones except for the  last bone in the IK chain in the required direction .This is because this bones local axis switch whenever the rotation limit angle is set.

Comment: @moonboots Sorry,had to change the question as the above issue was only seen in one chain and didn't exist for the other chains.Its still present in the above blend file (in the shoulder bone where limiting rotation to a single plane is not possible).

Comment: so you want your armature to work on its profile? In that case, why do you allow rotation on the Y axis? Also maybe bend the knees a bit forward so that Blender knows in what direction they need to point out.

Comment: This is a sidefacing rig for a 2d cutout animation(XZ plane)  and movement and rotation in Y axis is restricted .However even after applying IK constraints to the IK chain and location constraints to the IK target there is still rotation in the Y direction .I will upload the latest blend file with updated constraints, Also bones are already bent in XZ .plane

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110017/discussion-between-moonboots-and-starzar).

Comment: there is still a rotation because you have given a min -180 and max 180° to the Y, don't you want to give 0/0?

Comment: I have upload the updated blend file and sorry its too late here , may we look into this tommorow.Thanks

Comment: The rotation constraints are correct .They are with respect to the "local bone axis" (& not the global axis).Plz click on the bone in Pose mode to find the visual envelope for the rotation constraint,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bones in question were in not in ***"perfect alignment"*** with the view axis.

On aligning them to view and setting roll with `ARMARTURE - BONE ROLL - RECALCULATE ROLL - VIEW AXIS` , the bone roll was resolved.