# Why has IK rotation constraint "envelope" stopped displaying?

Tags: inverse-kinematics

Uptil yesterday,for the same Ik rig,  [IK rotation constraint ***"envelopes"(red line)***](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/184568/how-to-avoid-bone-roll-on-rotation-constrained-ik-bone?noredirect=1#comment309167_184568) were being displayed.

However today,with multidimensional constraints they no longer show.

Is there an option to toggle them ON?

[image]

[image]

Comment: weird, could you please share your file?

Comment: Hi,blend file uploaded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the *N* panel > *Display*, you need to activate the *Relationship Lines* option. In 2.8 it's in the *Viewport Overlays* panel:

[image]